# Keep Dynamic URL Content in URL on Each Page

Tags: php, url, dynamic, cookies

I have a PHP website that I send users to via a Dynamic URL like this:

```
http://mwebsitehere.com/?gw=1
```

well the page I send them too, works great with the code I am using to do certain things if the Dynamic content is set in the url. But whenever they click on a link on the page, which are ALWAYS changing, the Dynamic Content in the url is completely gone... For instances:

Lets say they are on the homepage that looks like this `http://mwebsitehere.com/?gw=1`, and then they click on a link that looks like this `http://mwebsitehere.com/new-page/`. Notice the `?gw=1` is completely gone from the url.

Is there a way to keep the Dynamic Links on every page if the url has dynamic content.

Like if it were to say `?gw=2` could all the links they click on or url somehow keep `?gw=2` on every page. Or if it said `?gw=1` for it to do the same thing.

Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if I need to explain my question better. Thanks!

I am also using wordpress, just in case you know anything wordpress specific! Thx!

Comment: @ScottWalker i see a php tag so i think he is :)

Comment: yes! sorry for not adding that to my question! I will make an edit!

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks, I wasnt thinking :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.

1. You may use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and put it in every single link in your page. It will keep your links always repeating the same query string that your current file is.
2. You should try storing data in sessions! Then you can carry data from a page to another. Take a look at the [PHP manual](http://php.net/session).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

the only reason to have get variables `?gw=2` in the url is if they are needed for that page, if you are wanting them for all pages,

have your scripts check to see if it exists in the $_GET array or $_COOKIES array, if its in the $_GET array but not it in the $_COOKIE array then set it in the cookies. That way your script will still see it,by checking the cookies.

No sense in cluttering the url with variables that dont need to always be shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact same variable passed to every page, why not use

```
    $_SESSION['gw'];
```

or

```
    $_COOKIE['gw'];
```

to store "gw".

Otherwise you would have to pass it on via each link as follows
For example on page http://mwebsitehere.com/?gw=1

```
     <a href="http://mwebsitehere.com/new-page/?gw=<? echo $gw; ?>">Link</a>
```